# Why the UIBezierPath is not working consistently with plus devices

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I am rounding the corners of view using `UIBezierPath`

```
var maskPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(vu.Bounds, UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight, new CGSize(5.0, 5.0));
var maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer{Frame = vu.Bounds,Path = maskPath.CGPath};
vu.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
```

Specifically in plus devices it causes problem.

for example if view has leading and trailing of 5 px

and If I try to round the view I can see that trailing space has something like 20 px and this happens only in plus devices

in some of the views.. the  label which is a child to parent view gets hidden partially on trailing side while the view's rounded trailing is right and it affects the child view..

the labels trailing is 0 to the rounded view 
If I don't round the corner then I don't have this problem the trailing is just 5 as designed.

so finally it makes me think UIBezierPath is not compatible with plus devices

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What are the values of vu.Bounds in plus and non plus devices.

Comment: You might want to add "Xamarin" to the title of your question. I got very confused at first. "Wait, is that Swift? No. It must be Objective-C. Wait, no, it's not that either. What **is** that?"  I started to post an answer but I don't know anything about Xamarin so I'm not qualified to help.

Comment: @DuncanC - that's what tags are for.  Putting tags in titles is not recommended

Comment: @MitchellCurrie - the bounds should be similar right ?

Comment: It's worth checking

Comment: The plus devices have 'triple pixels' The coordinates can be fractions of 1/3. like 10.67. You might want to make sure your frame and other rects have their coordinates normalized to whole values.

Comment: so if i round it .. it willl round the wrong place right ?can't i round the view with exact edge .i mean with decimal points

Comment: @PhoneyDeveloper - Can you please explain ?